# Typescript method name based on generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I have a class like:

```
class Foo<T extends string> { }
```

Now, I need to have an abstract method, the name of which is the value of `T`. Is that possible?

The use-case would look something like this:

```
class Bar extends Foo<'test'> {
    public override test(): void {
        // todo
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `I need to have an abstract method` mean? There is no such thing as abstract method, there is an abstract class maybe?

Comment: Yes the class needs to be abstract as well. But of course there is such a thing as abstract methods. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes.

Comment: thanks didn't know there's such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much **nothing** (with the exception of enums) will ever make it from the Type part of TypeScript into Javascript. It's a *compile time* aid for your development experience. Thus it is impossible to do what you ask.

There are advanced features like mapped types and the like, and they allow you to do amazing things deriving new *types* from existing ones. A powerful feature is something like

```js
type A = {
  ho: boolean;
  hi: number;
  hu: string;
}

type B<T> = {
 [key in keyof T]: () => void
};

// Property 'hu' is missing in type '{ ho: () => void; hi: () => void; }' 
// but required in type 'B<A>'
const obj: B<A> = { 
  ho: () => console.log('ho'),
  hi: () => console.log('hi')
}
```

but these are limited to types and otherwise. I recommend you check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on `extends` and `override` then you can do this with `implements`:

```
type Foo<T extends string> = {
    [_ in T]: () => void;
}

class Bar implements Foo<'test'> {
    public test() { /* todo */ }
}
```